# How to add headers to socketIO in flutter

Tags: flutter, socket.io

I try to connect socket io in dart. I use [socket_io_client: ^2.0.0-beta.4-nullsafety.0](https://pub.dev/packages/socket_io_client/versions/2.0.0-beta.4-nullsafety.0) for connection and use this code to connect:

```
Socket socket = io(
    '$server_address',
   OptionBuilder()
      .setTransports(['websocket'])
      .disableAutoConnect()
       .setExtraHeaders({'authorization': "$token"})
       .build());
socket.connect();
```

And it connects successfully. But, my headers (authorization) are not sent to the server. I also check my request and response with *inspect* of google chrome to make sure:

[image: Screenshot]

So, How can I send the headers with socket io?

Comment: use this _socket?.onConnect method insted of socket.connect();

Answer (score 1):

I think my answer is a bit late but it could help someone else. Anyway, I was facing the same issue and I found that socket_io_client in Flutter don't allow add extraHeader when you execute your app in the web (extraHeaders work fine in other platforms like Android or Windows), I think it is cause the securities restrictions of JavaScript when it's execute in a browser.

The solution that I found was use `.setAuth({'authorization': "$token"})` instead of `.setExtraHeaders({'authorization': "$token"})`. Your code should be like this:

```
final socket = io.io( url.toString(), 
      OptionBuilder()
        .setTransports(['websocket']) 
        .disableAutoConnect()
        .setAuth({'authorization': "$token" })
        .build()
);
socket.connect();
```

In the server side, you can get your token using this: (This example is in NodeJS).

```
export const socketOnConnection = async ( socket : Socket, io : SocketServer ) => {
    const token = socket.handshake.auth[ 'authorization' ] ;  
    // ... rest of your code here
}
```

I hope it be helpfull.